# Java RestTemplate.exchange returns 400 null exception

Tags: java, rest, resttemplate

I'm getting the following error when attempting a POST call using the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` class:

```
"400 null","stackTrace":"org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
```

Below is my code:

```
public void PostInsertOrUpdateDisplayCounts(CountsDataResults countsDataResults, String displayId) {

        String postUrl = "http://zld05300.vci.com:38767/application/display/C9B367BE340288EFE7D835FD587F2A3/counts";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpEntity<CountsDataResults> countsDataResultsEntity = new HttpEntity<CountsDataResults>(countsDataResults, headers);

        //execute the post call:
        ResponseEntity<Response> reponseEntity  = restTemplate.exchange(postUrl, HttpMethod.POST, countsDataResultsEntity, Response.class);

    }
```

Below is the server code that will be receiving the request:

```
@POST
    @Path("/application/display/{displayId}/counts")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response insertOrUpdateDisplayCounts(@RequestBody CountsDataResults countsList,@PathParam("displayId")String displayId);
```

Below is the implementation of the `insertOrUpdateDisplayCounts` method:

```
@Override
    public Response insertOrUpdateDisplayCounts(CountsDataResults countsList, String displayId) {
        String result = countsAPI.insertOrUpdateDisplayCountTables(countsList, displayId);
        if(result == "success")
            return Response.created(null).build();
        else
            return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }
```

I'm positive that the parameter arguments are non-null, and I have successfully tested this same POST call using postman to the endpoint and received the response I'm expecting -- why am I getting this exception?

Comment: Please post the code for `insertOrUpdateDisplayCounts()` and any relevant server logs, as the crash is happening at that end, I believe.

Comment: @KenY-N Post updated with the relevant info

Comment: I resolved the issue -- the problem was that I was sending an object of the type `CountsDataResults` when the server was expecting a `String` json.